# Facebook Open Graph action posting to News Feed, but Aggregation/Timeline NOT updating anymore

Tags: php, libcurl, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

At around 1pm EST, I was performing final tests on methods utilizing the Open Graph, when the timeline aggregation and individual stories stopped updating.

I could continue to add open graph actions to my developer account, the debug tool still worked and showed no issues, I am using the PHP SDK(1) which is not throwing any exceptions, and I am using the same curl(2) commands which have working repeatedly in the past.

Ironically, this stoppage in functionality has occurred during final tests.  I thought it may be a lag issue or something, so I waited a while today.  No luck!

In addition, that POST request addition was of a 'fine-tuning' nature.  They were simply to act as a **one-time request per object** to ensure Facebook could scrape or had scraped the object. Now aggregation doesn't work anymore?  I doubt they're related, at least I hope not!

Any ideas?

(1) still works: the request to get object id (note: I use a namespace called 'Services_Facebook' through which to access the latest PHP SDK):

```
try {
    // tested and confirmed that this will work the same as a direct POST curl_exec as per FB doc: http://bit.ly/oENw60
    $opengraph_object_array = Services_Facebook::api('/', 'POST', array(
        'id' => $canonical_url,
        'scrape' => 'true'
    ));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $opengraph_object_array = NULL;
}
if ($opengraph_object_array && isset($opengraph_object_array['id'])) {
    $opengraph_object_id = $opengraph_object_array['id'];
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

(2) still works: the format of the curl command I have been using has remained unchanged:

```
curl -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
    -F 'scrape=true' \
    -F 'app=<url of the OG object>' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/<app namespace>:<action>'
```